# Check for existing key in AsyncStorage

Tags: react-native, navigation, token, asyncstorage

I want to display the right navigator based on AsyncStorage, I searched here but always the same result:

```
 const signedIn = async () => {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
    if(token) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

It always returns true..

Answer (score 1):

The signedIn function is returning a promise. If you are invoking the function like below,
then every time we will navigate to **SCREEN1**.

```
let response = signedIn();
if(response){
   console.log("SCREEN1")
   //Navigate to SCREEN 1
 }else{
   console.log("SCREEN2")
   // Navigate to SCREEN 2
}
```

Rather than you should call it like this

```
signedIn().then((response)=>{
  if(response){
     console.log("SCREEN1")
     //Navigate to SCREEN 1
   }else{
     console.log("SCREEN2")
     // Navigate to SCREEN 2
  }
 })
```

Or In this way { calling function should be async }

```
let response = await signedIn()
if(response){
   console.log("SCREEN1")
   //Navigate to SCREEN 1
}else{
   console.log("SCREEN2")
   // Navigate to SCREEN 2
}
```